# What is FTL engine speed good for?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In "Faster Than Light" each upgrade of the ship's engine increases dodge factor, but also it increases you FTL speed, which starts at 1 and goes up to 2.75.

What is FTL engine speed good for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not your FTL speed, but the rate your FTL charges at while in combat.

http://ftlwiki.com/wiki/Systems#Engines

```
Upgrading improves dodge chance and the rate that your FTL drive charges
```

Faster charging is useful when you want to get out of a sector sooner without fighting.